# When do the most people come and go inside the stadium?

Tags: calculus

$60$ Minutes before the beginning of a football match the door of the stadium opens for the audience.

We have a graph with the arrival rate of the audience:

[image]

When do the most people come to the stadium?

Do we look when the slope is the biggest? Or when the graph is at the heighest point?

I suppose that at the period $40$ to $15$ minutes before the most people come. Is this correct?

Comment: The question "when do the most people come ...? is not clear. But you should be able to construct the graph of the function that has time on the $x$-axis and the total in the stadium on the $y$-axis.

Comment: What are those negative numbers?

Comment: For example $-60$ means $60$ before the match begins. @cgiovanardi

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** On a graph where the y-axis is the rate ($f'(t)$) and the x-axis is time ($t$), the area under the curve represents the accumulation.

In your example, the area under the curve on any interval $[t_1,t_2]$ represents the number of people that enter the stadium during that interval.

Comment: So, we have to compute the area of the intervalls $[-80, -60]$, $[-60, -40]$, $[-40, -15]$ and $[-15, 10]$. so evry time where the curve changes slope?

Comment: Computing the area of the intervals and adding will give you total audience. And between 40 and 15 minutes before the beginning of the match we have maximum affluence or rate of people entering the stadium.